# Linux mint has just crashed - Jessie 8 (LMDE)

Tags: debian, linux-mint, cinnamon, crash

I did a normal update to the system last night and after reboot my computer just stopped working and keeps falling back to 'fallback mode'. I tried to reinstall Cinnamon without success. I tried to reinstall AIT drivers - no success. Does anyone have ideas?

```
[    2.083224] i8042: Warning: Keylock active
[    2.085645] serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
[    2.085648] serio: i8042 AUX port at 0x60,0x64 irq 12
[    2.085731] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    2.085813] rtc_cmos 00:02: RTC can wake from S4
[    2.085918] rtc_cmos 00:02: rtc core: registered rtc_cmos as rtc0
[    2.085949] rtc_cmos 00:02: alarms up to one month, y3k, 242 bytes nvram, hpet irqs
[    2.085956] Intel P-state driver initializing.
[    2.085973] Intel pstate controlling: cpu 0
[    2.085985] Intel pstate controlling: cpu 1
[    2.085998] Intel pstate controlling: cpu 2
[    2.086013] Intel pstate controlling: cpu 3
[    2.086110] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    2.087280] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input0
[    2.088998] AMD IOMMUv2 driver by Joerg Roedel <joerg.roedel@amd.com>
[    2.089001] AMD IOMMUv2 functionality not available on this system
[    2.089198] TCP: cubic registered
[    2.089357] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    2.089826] mip6: Mobile IPv6
[    2.089836] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    2.089851] mpls_gso: MPLS GSO support
[    2.090202] registered taskstats version 1
[    2.090773] rtc_cmos 00:02: setting system clock to 2015-06-25 12:21:04 UTC (1435234864)
[    2.090837] PM: Hibernation image not present or could not be loaded.
[    2.091351] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1204K (ffffffff818ee000 - ffffffff81a1b000)
[    2.091352] Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 8192k
[    2.092668] Freeing unused kernel memory: 924K (ffff880001519000 - ffff880001600000)
[    2.093360] Freeing unused kernel memory: 216K (ffff8800017ca000 - ffff880001800000)
[    2.112196] systemd-udevd[76]: starting version 215
[    2.112367] random: systemd-udevd urandom read with 6 bits of entropy available
[    2.116736] input: Lid Switch as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input2
[    2.117422] ACPI: Lid Switch [LID0]
[    2.117473] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input3
[    2.117477] ACPI: Power Button [PBTN]
[    2.117524] input: Sleep Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input4
[    2.117526] ACPI: Sleep Button [SBTN]
[    2.117574] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input5
[    2.117576] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
[    2.121219] wmi: Mapper loaded
[    2.121824] pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
[    2.121825] pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
[    2.121968] PTP clock support registered
[    2.122829] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 2.3.2-k
[    2.122830] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2014 Intel Corporation.
[    2.123380] ACPI: bus type USB registered
[    2.123402] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    2.123411] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    2.123437] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[    2.123450] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    2.123963] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    2.124135] ehci-pci: EHCI PCI platform driver
[    2.126105] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    2.126274] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    2.126275] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    2.126568] sdhci-pci 0000:0e:00.0: SDHCI controller found [1217:8520] (rev 1)
[    2.127348] libata version 3.00 loaded.
[    2.162168] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[    2.162196] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: irq 43 for MSI/MSI-X
[    2.162243] mmc0: Unknown controller version (3). You may experience problems.
[    2.162301] mmc0: no vqmmc regulator found
[    2.162302] mmc0: no vmmc regulator found
[    2.162423] mmc0: SDHCI controller on PCI [0000:0e:00.0] using ADMA
[    2.378183] thermal LNXTHERM:00: registered as thermal_zone0
[    2.378185] ACPI: Thermal Zone [THM] (25 C)
[    2.425522] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: registered PHC clock
[    2.425525] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) f0:1f:af:37:22:9d
[    2.425526] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    2.425569] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: MAC: 11, PHY: 12, PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
[    2.425718] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    2.425724] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    2.425815] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: cache line size of 64 is not supported
[    2.425834] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: irq 44 for MSI/MSI-X
[    2.425941] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    2.425942] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    2.425943] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    2.425944] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 xhci_hcd
[    2.425945] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    2.426035] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.426069] hub 1-0:1.0: 15 ports detected
[    2.427771] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    2.427774] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    2.427845] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
[    2.427846] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    2.427847] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    2.427848] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 xhci_hcd
[    2.427848] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    2.427929] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.427946] hub 2-0:1.0: 6 ports detected
[    2.428756] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: EHCI Host Controller
[    2.428761] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
[    2.428777] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: debug port 2
[    2.432683] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: cache line size of 64 is not supported
[    2.432695] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: irq 16, io mem 0xf7d3c000
[    2.442069] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    2.442092] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    2.442094] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    2.442095] usb usb3: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    2.442096] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 ehci_hcd
[    2.442096] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1a.0
[    2.442182] hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.442185] hub 3-0:1.0: 3 ports detected
[    2.442358] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: EHCI Host Controller
[    2.442362] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 4
[    2.442372] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: debug port 2
[    2.446266] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: cache line size of 64 is not supported
[    2.446276] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: irq 21, io mem 0xf7d3b000
[    2.458071] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    2.458097] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    2.458099] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    2.458101] usb usb4: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    2.458102] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 ehci_hcd
[    2.458103] usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.0
[    2.458186] hub 4-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.458189] hub 4-0:1.0: 3 ports detected
[    2.458318] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: version 3.0
[    2.458428] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X
[    2.458447] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: SSS flag set, parallel bus scan disabled
[    2.458467] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: AHCI 0001.0300 32 slots 5 ports 6 Gbps 0x7 impl RAID mode
[    2.458469] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: flags: 64bit ncq ilck stag pm led clo pio slum part ems sxs apst 
[    2.474572] scsi0 : ahci
[    2.474684] scsi1 : ahci
[    2.474774] scsi2 : ahci
[    2.474861] scsi3 : ahci
[    2.474948] scsi4 : ahci
[    2.474991] ata1: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xf7d3a000 port 0xf7d3a100 irq 45
[    2.474994] ata2: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xf7d3a000 port 0xf7d3a180 irq 45
[    2.474996] ata3: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xf7d3a000 port 0xf7d3a200 irq 45
[    2.474997] ata4: DUMMY
[    2.474998] ata5: DUMMY
[    2.475319] [drm] Memory usable by graphics device = 2048M
[    2.475321] [drm] Replacing VGA console driver
[    2.476302] Console: switching to colour dummy device 80x25
[    2.530203] i915 0000:00:02.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X
[    2.530214] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    2.530215] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[    2.530240] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:00:02.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=none
[    2.557247] [drm] VBT doesn't support DRRS
[    2.738203] usb 1-3: new full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    2.794187] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[    2.794391] ata1.00: ATA-8: OCZ-ARC100, 1.01, max UDMA/133
[    2.794394] ata1.00: 468862128 sectors, multi 1: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA
[    2.795411] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    2.795515] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      OCZ-ARC100       1.01 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    2.831879] fbcon: inteldrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    2.868437] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c52b
[    2.868438] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.868439] usb 1-3: Product: USB Receiver
[    2.868439] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Logitech
[    2.869859] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    2.873292] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    2.873292] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    2.874475] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C52B.0003: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3/input2
[    2.934425] input: Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:4002 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0003/0003:046D:C52B.0004/input/input6
[    2.934480] logitech-djdevice 0003:046D:C52B.0004: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:4002] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3:1
[    2.936353] input: Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:101a as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0003/0003:046D:C52B.0005/input/input7
[    2.936449] logitech-djdevice 0003:046D:C52B.0005: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:101a] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3:2
[    3.034269] usb 1-9: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    3.058258] tsc: Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 2893.304 MHz
[    3.114281] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[    3.116034] ata2.00: ATAPI: MATSHITA DVD+/-RW UJ8C2, 1.02, max UDMA/133
[    3.117490] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    3.118892] scsi 1:0:0:0: CD-ROM            MATSHITA DVD+-RW UJ8C2    1.02 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    3.165901] usb 1-9: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=07da
[    3.165903] usb 1-9: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    3.278371] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    3.410786] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=8008
[    3.410787] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    3.410990] hub 3-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    3.411086] hub 3-1:1.0: 6 ports detected
[    3.446356] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    3.448285] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 468862128 512-byte logical blocks: (240 GB/223 GiB)
[    3.448300] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    3.448301] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    3.448306] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    3.448717]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3
[    3.448876] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    3.456492] sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 24x/24x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[    3.456493] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
[    3.456577] sr 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[    3.456930] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[    3.456965] sr 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
[    3.522395] usb 4-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    3.654829] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=8000
[    3.654830] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    3.655053] hub 4-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    3.655170] hub 4-1:1.0: 8 ports detected
[    3.726591] usb 3-1.5: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[    3.892190] usb 3-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=0c45, idProduct=64d0
[    3.892191] usb 3-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[    3.892192] usb 3-1.5: Product: Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_HD
[    3.892193] usb 3-1.5: Manufacturer: CN0767N972487381B6A5A00
[    3.990500] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 210x65
[    3.993232] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
[    3.993233] i915 0000:00:02.0: registered panic notifier
[    4.026972] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PEGP) defines _DOD but not _DOS
[    4.027464] ACPI: Video Device [PEGP] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[    4.027518] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:4b/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input8
[    4.028375] ACPI: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[    4.058541] Switched to clocksource tsc
[    4.090648] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:01/input/input9
[    4.090692] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20080730 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[    4.097930] device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
[    4.097991] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.27.0-ioctl (2013-10-30) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
[    4.144101] PM: Starting manual resume from disk
[    4.144104] PM: Hibernation image partition 8:1 present
[    4.144105] PM: Looking for hibernation image.
[    4.144163] PM: Image not found (code -22)
[    4.144164] PM: Hibernation image not present or could not be loaded.
[    4.168544] EXT4-fs (sda2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    4.331451] systemd-udevd[365]: starting version 215
[    4.388071] shpchp: Standard Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.4
[    4.388994] ACPI: AC Adapter [AC] (on-line)
[    4.392055] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: irq 47 for MSI/MSI-X
[    4.395502] parport_pc 00:07: [io  0x0378-0x037b]
[    4.395553] parport_pc 00:07: [irq 5]
[    4.415018] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[    4.415625] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: irq 48 for MSI/MSI-X
[    4.415749] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 49 for MSI/MSI-X
[    4.415850] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x000000000000f040-0x000000000000f05f conflicts with OpRegion 0x000000000000f040-0x000000000000f04f (\_SB_.PCI0.SBUS.SMBI) (20140424/utaddress-258)
[    4.415856] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[    4.418905] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux, in-tree:
[    4.418907] Copyright(c) 2003- 2014 Intel Corporation
[    4.419065] input: PC Speaker as /devices/platform/pcspkr/input/input10
[    4.424697] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.19
[    4.424705] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[    4.424706] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.424711] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.424713] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.424719] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.429655] sound hdaudioC1D0: autoconfig: line_outs=1 (0x16/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:line
[    4.429657] sound hdaudioC1D0:    speaker_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    4.429658] sound hdaudioC1D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x15/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    4.429659] sound hdaudioC1D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    4.429660] sound hdaudioC1D0:    inputs:
[    4.429661] sound hdaudioC1D0:      Dock Mic=0x19
[    4.429662] sound hdaudioC1D0:      Headset Mic=0x1a
[    4.429663] sound hdaudioC1D0:      Internal Mic=0x12
[    4.436232] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input16
[    4.436283] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input17
[    4.436343] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input18
[    4.436422] input: HDA Digital PCBeep as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/hdaudioC1D0/input12
[    4.436651] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[    4.436679] input: HDA Intel PCH Dock Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input13
[    4.436709] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: irq 50 for MSI/MSI-X
[    4.436818] input: HDA Intel PCH Dock Line Out as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input14
[    4.437110] AVX2 version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.
[    4.437216] input: HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input15
[    4.439322] alg: No test for __gcm-aes-aesni (__driver-gcm-aes-aesni)
[    4.441062] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[    4.442872] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
[    4.443065] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 18.168.6.1 op_mode iwldvm
[    4.443712] dcdbas dcdbas: Dell Systems Management Base Driver (version 5.6.0-3.2)
[    4.466477] alg: No test for crc32 (crc32-pclmul)
[    4.469964] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
[    4.469966] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS disabled
[    4.469967] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING disabled
[    4.469968] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6235 AGN, REV=0xB0
[    4.470010] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
[    4.473242] fglrx: module license 'Proprietary. (C) 2002 - ATI Technologies, Starnberg, GERMANY' taints kernel.
[    4.473244] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[    4.482182] media: Linux media interface: v0.10
[    4.483772] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain package
[    4.483778] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain core
[    4.483781] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain uncore
[    4.483782] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain dram
[    4.484860] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[    4.489022] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
[    4.489332] input: Dell WMI hotkeys as /devices/virtual/input/input19
[    4.491319] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_HD (0c45:64d0)
[    4.498585] <6>[fglrx] Maximum main memory to use for locked dma buffers: 7677 MBytes.
[    4.498744] <6>[fglrx]   vendor: 1002 device: 6606 count: 1
[    4.498966] <6>[fglrx] ioport: bar 4, base 0xe000, size: 0x100
[    4.498971] pci 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[    4.503440] <6>[fglrx] Kernel PAT support is enabled
[    4.503454] <6>[fglrx] module loaded - fglrx 14.20.7 [Sep  2 2014] with 1 minors
[    4.506856] iTCO_vendor_support: vendor-support=0
[    4.506958] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[    4.507374] iTCO_wdt: Intel TCO WatchDog Timer Driver v1.11
[    4.507402] iTCO_wdt: Found a Lynx Point TCO device (Version=2, TCOBASE=0x1860)
[    4.507454] iTCO_wdt: initialized. heartbeat=30 sec (nowayout=0)
[    4.529161] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[    4.529163] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[    4.529164] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[    4.529166] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    4.529167] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    4.529169] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    4.529171] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    4.529173] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[    4.529174] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[    4.529176] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    4.529178] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[    4.532171] input: Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_HD as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.5/3-1.5:1.0/input/input20
[    4.532250] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[    4.532251] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[    4.546870] parport_pc 00:07: activated
[    4.546873] parport_pc 00:07: reported by Plug and Play ACPI
[    4.548492] parport_pc 00:07: disabled
[    4.554218] ACPI: Battery Slot [BAT0] (battery present)
[    4.658690] ACPI: Battery Slot [BAT1] (battery absent)
[    4.786770] [drm] Enabling RC6 states: RC6 on, RC6p off, RC6pp off
[    5.671712] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[    5.674748] Adding 8388604k swap on /dev/sda1.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:8388604k SSFS
[    5.683514] EXT4-fs (sda2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[    5.722857] EXT4-fs (sda2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[    5.739347] input: DualPoint Stick as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input21
[    5.751385] input: AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input11
[    5.841161] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[    5.897032] fuse init (API version 7.23)
[    5.981893] EXT4-fs (sda3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[    6.707882] systemd-logind[2116]: New seat seat0.
[    6.711031] systemd-logind[2116]: Failed to start user service: Unknown unit: user@1000.service
[    6.712919] systemd-logind[2116]: New session c1 of user maciej.
[    6.717355] input: BRLTTY 5.2dev Linux Screen Driver Keyboard as /devices/virtual/input/input22
[    7.250634] systemd-logind[2116]: Removed session c1.
[    8.658795] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    8.658797] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    8.658804] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    8.667852] systemd-hostnamed[2849]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
[    8.848794] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: irq 43 for MSI/MSI-X
[    8.951617] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: irq 43 for MSI/MSI-X
[    8.951699] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[    8.953129] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
[    8.959982] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x1-0x0
[    9.233274] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
[    9.240020] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x1-0x0
[    9.327933] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   15.750928] wlan0: authenticate with d0:2d:b3:54:df:dc
[   15.755226] wlan0: send auth to d0:2d:b3:54:df:dc (try 1/3)
[   15.844465] wlan0: authenticated
[   15.845094] wlan0: associate with d0:2d:b3:54:df:dc (try 1/3)
[   15.855699] wlan0: RX AssocResp from d0:2d:b3:54:df:dc (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=3)
[   15.858001] wlan0: associated
[   15.858023] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[   15.858051] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: GB
[   15.859706] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: GB
[   15.859709] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: ETSI
[   15.859710] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[   15.859711] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   15.859712] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   15.859713] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[   15.859714] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2700 mBm), (0 s)
[   15.859715] cfg80211:   (57000000 KHz - 66000000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm), (N/A)
[   21.680373] systemd-logind[2116]: New session 1 of user maciej.
```

I have installed iceWM as a 'failsafe dsktop' and I have uninstalled Cinnamon completely and re-installed it and the same thing happens. I got message the same message: Cinnamon just crashed.

Comment: Can you run `dmesg`  or `less /var/log/messages` in a plain console?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yes and i can see this error : Failed to start user service : Unknow unit: user@1000.service, Unknown controller version (3). You may experience problems. <-these are red messages

Comment: Edit your question to show these messages (and the few lines before)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Will try ;) but its not going to be easy since its a fallback mode i can barely do anything ;o!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Ok so log output attached. The problem only appeared after i did update last night. Before system was working fine.

Comment: Nothing wrong, IIRC. It looks like your command line Linux is working well. The Graphical User Interface is just a detail.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25188/discussion-between-basile-starynkevitch-and-maciej-cygan).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch well do you have anything at the back of your head what could cause the cinnamon to crash ? i have just installed KDE-plasma and it works just fine (although its ugly as fck)

Comment: I am trying to chat with you, will give up soon unless you respond quickly.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Ah yes sorry did not realise :) i'm on chat now